# CLI php run php in command prompt

Tags: php, ubuntu, console

I have installed PHP CLI to execute php commands from console.

I have installed PHP CLI using this command -

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

When I run this

```
$vr=3; echo $vr;
```

Result :-

```
=3: command not found
```

If I run `echo "test";`
Result :- `test`

displays..

Can anyone tell why `"command not found"` displays..

Comment: Are you running the commands directly in the console? Then, the first one fails, but the second one is not executing PHP's `echo` but the one of the shell ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "echo "test" line is working because echo is a bash command.

You have to write your own php script, the run it by command line like this:

```
$ php myscript.php
```

In alternative, you can run `php` from your command line, then directly write or paste your script.
Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to run it. Remember the  at the beginning and at the end.

As third option, you can write a php script, putting in the first line this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Obviously the php executable path must match the one in your system.
This way, you can chmod +x the script, then run it directly like this:

```
$ ./myscript.php
```

The fourth option is the [interactive shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php):

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo 5+8;
13
```

[$ in front of commands means a command run by user]

Answer (score 2):

You are entering PHP code into the Unix shell (*e.g.* bash). The Unix shell does not understand PHP code, so you have to run `php` first.

To run your PHP code from the command line:

```
$ php -r '$vr=3; echo $vr, "\n";'
3
```

To run your PHP code from the PHP [interactive shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) (which may or may not be compiled into PHP):

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $vr=3; echo $vr, "\n";
3
php >
```

(Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or type `exit` to get out of the PHP shell.)

To run your PHP code from a file named `prog.php` (which contains `<?php` before the code):

```
$ php prog.php
3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

This gives you an interactive mode, where you can type PHP code and have it executed directly.